# mysqli_set_charset gives error on one machine

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to machines where I use XAMPP for developing. I just moved the files from one machine to another and now I get a error when calling mysqli_set_charset and then bind_param. It works on one machine.

EDIT: This is the error I get:

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

My code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123", "myDatabase");
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");

//Checks if the user exists
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE email = ? AND password = md5(?) LIMIT 1");
$stmt -> mysqli_stmt_bind_param("ss", $email, $pass);
$stmt -> execute();
```

EDIT #2:

The machine that it works on uses PHP 5.3.1 in XAMPP on Mac OS 10.8.1, there isn't a newer version of XAMPP yet.

The machine that it doesn't work on uses PHP 5.4.4 in XAMPP on Windows 7.

If I remove the line that says `mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");` it works on both machines, otherwise, only on the Mac.

EDIT #3:

I tested to change `password = md5(?)` to just `password = ?` and then it works. Well the passwords doesn't match but I no longer get the error. I'm not going to use md5 in the future but I want to use it just for now and I need to have charset set to utf8. How do I solve that?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of a hurry when writing this, see the edit.

Comment: Show the around the line where it fails, please

Answer (score 0):

If your other machine is running PHP 5.4:

```
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
```

(from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-bind-param.php )
bind_param was an alias for mysqli_stmt_bind_param - you should use that

If it's not PHP 5.4, we need more information, like your actual code.

Comment: I tested to change bind_param to mysqli_stmt_bind_param but I still get the same error (PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function mysqli_stmt_bind_param() on a non-object) Where can I see which PHP version I'm using?

Comment: put phpinfo() into a page to get back all the info about your php version you want.

Comment: since you've edited your question it no longer makes complete sense. You're describing the error as "PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" still but it's a problem presumably with your call to MD5. The question has changed: what is the new error saying?

Comment: I still get the same error but if I edit the original code by only changing `md5(?)` to `?`, the error disappears. Though the passwords doesn't match. It works fine with `md5(?)` on the machine running PHP 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Following code should be fine:

```
PHP
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE email = ? AND password = md5(?) LIMIT 1");
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $email, $pass);
$stmt -> execute();
```